# how to set dynamic arguments for a process?

Tags: c#, bash, process

**In bash**

I run the following kill commands (it's just a kill with an expression which return the ID of a process)

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep '[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector' | cut -f8 -d' ')
```

which return something like

```
kill 800
```

**When I try to run this in C#**

```
Process.Start("kill", "$(ps -ef | grep '[m]atchbox-panel --titlebar --start-applets showdesktop,windowselector' | cut -f8 -d' ')");
```

I get a fatal error.

**Alternative**

I could run all the commands one by one until I have the number and set a process with "kill" and the "number", but it seems a lot of trouble for what it does.

Comment: Either you feed it to the `bash` operator, or you have to execute the tree yourself.

Comment: $(..) is not evaluated in a Process.Start argument, that is a feature of bash. You can split your command in two lines, or try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(..) is not evaluated in a Process.Start argument, that is a feature of bash.  You can split your command in two lines, or try `pkill`.